# What does " if(*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL) " check?

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I came across a piece of code as following:

```
/* Allocate memory for _ptr */

if(*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL)
{
   /* free _ptr */
}
```

What is it different from the following?

```
/* Allocate memory for _ptr */

if (_ptr != NULL )
{
   /* free _ptr */
}
```

EDIT:　_ptr may be any type, actually, this is a macro as following:

```
#define RETURN_MEM_CHK(_ptr)   \
    {if(*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL){/* free _ptr */}
```

Sorry about bringing confusion.

Comment: Did you mean `if (_ptr != NULL)`?

Comment: Looks like a line from an obfuscated C programming contest

Comment: It's also unnecessary; one doesn't need to check for NULL before invoking `free` on a pointer.

Comment: What is type of _ptr?

Comment: `*(void **)&_ptr` is useful when you need convert _ptr to a `void *` lvalue. There is no difference from (void *)_ptr if one wants a rvalue.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I will that not give a segmentation fault? or double free error?... I experienced it once on a linux system with a long stack trace.. please correct me if I've some misconception

Comment: @pinkpanther: The standard mandates that `free` gracefully deals with `NULL` arguments.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've just checked on windows...`#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
 int *r=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
 free(r);
 free(r);
 return 0;
}` ..... gave me filename.exe stopped working message box ?

Comment: @pinkpanther: `r` is not a null pointer...

Comment: @pinkpanther And, passing NULL to free has nothing to do with double-free: you only get that if you call free twice!

Comment: @NicholasWilson yeah, I got it now :)

Comment: Is this the real code, or the result of macro expansion?

Answer (score 16):

**For what it's worth:**

I couldn't figure this out on my own, so I've discussed this with my compiler and he says the condition is equivalent* to `if (_ptr != NULL)`:

> % gcc -Wall -O2 -g -c convoluted.c; objdump -d -M intel -S convoluted.o

```
convoluted.o:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <main>:
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
   void* _ptr=malloc(1024);
   9:   c7 04 24 00 04 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x400
  10:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   11 <main+0x11>

   if(*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL)
  15:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
  17:   74 08                   je     21 <main+0x21>
   {
      free(_ptr);
  19:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
  1c:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1d <main+0x1d>
   }

   return 0;
}
  21:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  23:   c9                      leave  
  24:   c3                      ret
```

> % gcc -Wall -O2 -g -c kindanormal.c; objdump -d -M intel -S kindanormal.o

```
kindanormal.o:     file format elf32-i386
Disassembly of section .text.startup:

00000000 <main>:
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   0:   55                      push   ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    esp,0xfffffff0
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    esp,0x10
   void* _ptr=malloc(1024);
   9:   c7 04 24 00 04 00 00    mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x400
  10:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   11 <main+0x11>

   if(_ptr != NULL)
  15:   85 c0                   test   eax,eax
  17:   74 08                   je     21 <main+0x21>
   {
      free(_ptr);
  19:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
  1c:   e8 fc ff ff ff          call   1d <main+0x1d>
   }

   return 0;
}
  21:   31 c0                   xor    eax,eax
  23:   c9                      leave  
  24:   c3                      ret
```

**Note** 
The check itself isn't really necessary either, as other have pointed out. A more natural way would be to just do:

> free(_ptr);
>   _ptr=NULL;

*On this machine, with this OS and this GCC version and this CPU and only when the stars align in just the right way...

Comment: I assume your _ptr was a pointer variable, and not, for example, an int?

Comment: The OP said it was ptr to memory. I didn't explore any other scenarios

Comment: The condition is, of course, not equivalent from the point of view of C language. It just happens to be equivalent on your specific platform.

Comment: I won't downvote because of the proper disclaimer and exemplary effort, but there are too many upvotes here. This is not the correct way to approach this question, because what really is being asked is whether it does something which might make it work under exotic conditions.

Answer (score 12):

One example where it could give different results (and did, on my particular system, when I just tried it):

```
int _ptr = 0;
int whatever = 17;

if (*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL) {
    printf("Not equal (1)\n");
}

if (_ptr != NULL) {
    printf("Not equal (2)\n");
}
```

The first version pretends that the integer variable **_ptr** is a void pointer, and accesses its memory as if it was a void pointer. On my computer, where ints are 32 bits and pointers are 64 bits, this means reading memory outside the variable. This is of course undefined behavior, and in this case it resulted in the condition evaluating to true.

You would get similar results if **_ptr** is a pointer of a type other than **void***, on a system where that pointer type is of different size or represented differently than a void pointer.

Answer (score 6):

Well, what the difference is depends on what the type of `_ptr` is.

```
if (_ptr != NULL )
```

would not work if `_ptr` is not a pointer type (and `NULL` is a null pointer constant that includes a cast to `void*`, it could work if `NULL` is just an integer constant with value 0 even if `_ptr` does not have pointer type).

If `_ptr` has pointer type, `if (_ptr != NULL )` compares `_ptr` with a null pointer. Simples.

```
if(*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL)
```

if it does not invoke undefined behaviour, interprets the `sizeof (void*)` bytes starting at address `&_ptr` as a `void*` and compares the result of that reinterpretation to a null pointer of type `void*`.

It could behave differently if `_ptr` is a value of a pointer type with different representation than `void*`.

It works if `_ptr` is not of pointer type.

In all reasonable situations, however, it would just be a more complicated way of saying

```
if ((void*)_ptr != NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

`*((void **) &(_ptr)) != (void *) NULL`

This check also works where `_ptr` is not a pointer type, e.g. if `_ptr` was a `uintptr_t` or something. In this case, the simple comparison `_ptr != NULL` might not handle systems where null pointer values did not have an "all zero" representation.

Of course, reading an integer as pointer is not portable either so this code trades one set of problems for a different set of problems.

Comment: The null pointer always compares equal to a integer value of 0, no matter what the system internal representation is. Also see this C FAQ entry: http://c-faq.com/null/ptrtest.html

Comment: @datenwolf: An integer constant of value zero always converts to a null pointer value which will always compare equal to a null pointer. The null pointer value may not have an all zero representation. If `_ptr` is of an integer type but contains the representation of a null pointer (e.g. through a `memcpy` or a cast such as `*(void*)&_ptr = (void*)NULL`) then it may have a non-zero _integer_ value and will compare as not equal to zero.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Sorry, but the statement `*(void*)&_ptr = (void*)NULL` won't compile, since you can't dereference a `void*`. Or the first asterisk was a typo, but the expression `(void*)&_ptr` wouldn't expose the internal representation either; it would merely turn a pointer to `_ptr` of type `uintptr_t*` into a `void*`. Using just C it is impossible to expose the internal representation of a pointer; all attempts in doing so invoke undefined behavior. Your best bet in actually retrieving the internal representation would be the use of inline assembly.

Comment: @datenwolf: Sorry, I meant `(void**)` like in the comparison.

Comment: @datenwolf: If you want to be absolutely sure of avoiding undefined behaviour then you can read the representation of a pointer by casting a pointer to the pointer to a `char*` or `unsigned char*` and reading the underlying bytes. Obviously the comparison in the question causes undefined behavior so to answer the question you really have to consider likely practical outcomes on real systems. As I said, reading an integer as a pointer is not portable. That doesn't mean that it can't have useful behaviour on some systems some of the time.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: The cast you're suggesting also invokes undefined behavior. Pointer casts are defined only toward uintptr_t and void* and from uintptr_t and void* only if the value of the "untyped" pointer was originally yielded by a cast from the target type. I.e. `struct foo *spam, *eggs; uintptr_t _ptr = (void*)obj; eggs = (struct foo*)_ptr;` is defined, while `struct foo *spam; int *eggs; uintptr_t _ptr = (void*)obj; eggs = (int*)_ptr;` is undefined, despite they're both pointers. It would be valid for a implementation to detect this and throw some system level exception (segfault or such)

Comment: @datenwolf: Yes, I agree it would be.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
*((void **) &(_ptr)
```

expression performs raw-memory reinterpretation of the memory region occupied by object `_ptr`. The first `sizeof(void *)` bytes are reinterpreted as an object of `void *` type. Meanwhile, the object `_ptr` itself can have absolutely any type. It is natural to assume that it is intended to be an object of the same size as `void *` (or greater size).

For example, `_ptr` can be an object of some integral type of appropriate size. Obviously in that case `if (_ptr == NULL)` might simply refuse to compile in an implementation that defines `NULL` as `(void *) 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless `_ptr` has `void*` type then the code breaks strict aliasing rules and has undefined behavior:

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
>   expression that has one of the following types: 76)
>
> — a type compatible
>   with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a qualified version of a type
>   compatible with the effective type of the object,
>
> — a type that is the
>   signed or unsigned type corresponding to the effective type of the
>   object, —a type that is the signed or unsigned type corresponding to a
>   qualified version of the effective type of the object,
>
> — anaggregate or
>   union type that includes one of the aforementioned types among its
>   members (including, recursively ,amember of a subaggregate or
>   contained union), or
>
> —a character type.

In the code `_ptr` is accessed through lvalue of type `void*`, which is only *compatible* with itself, so none of the above conditions are true otherwise.

There's a good chance that it works like `_ptr != NULL` but using code like that is still a terrible practice.